# What is the best way of using response of first call as request payload for second call in Node.js without using promises?

Tags: node.js, request, node-modules

I am trying to make 2 /POST calls in Node.js. I want to use some fields of response of first call as payload for second call. The implementation i am aware of is as folllows:

```
function abc(reqObject, callback){
  request(reqObject, function(err,res)){
    if(err)
    {
      callback(err, null);
    }
    else
    {
      <use this res for second req>
      request(reqObject, function(err,res)){
       <err,res handling here>
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What is the most appropriate way(without messing up with callbacks) to achieve this **without using promises and async modules**? I am trying to do this **using only request module**.

Comment: If you do not want to use promise and async module(but why not) what you are doing is perfectly fine other than not in the write format. You can try request-promise https://github.com/request/request-promise this will by default return a promise so you do not need to wrap your request inside a promise.

Comment: Thanks Mustafa. I am bound to use only request module and thats why i am not using promise or async.

Comment: try the answer I gave should work.

Comment: Thanks. The approach i mentioned is working fine( I missed the closing braces of request() ). I just want to know if there is any other and more efficient way to do this.

Answer (score -1):

You are doing almost everything right. Only the braces are not in the right position.

```
function abc(reqObject, callback){
 request(reqObject, function(err,res){
   if(err)
  {
  callback(err, null);
}
else
{
  // <use this res for second req>
  request(reqObject, function(err,res){
  //  <err,res handling here>
 });
}
});
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.